# Outlook Calendar 2013 Automatic Accept

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I work at a law enforcement agency. Our deputies have multiple court dates each month. We have a designated "court" calendar on Outlook.  When sending a meeting request to each deputy, a majority of the time they do not "accept" the meeting request and this is a cause for missed court. I know of the auto accept feature, but trying to get 200 deputies to set this up on their Outlook settings is almost impossible.  Is there a way to have the court dates I create automatically placed on their calendars without them having to do anything on their end?  Thanks

Comment: The only way I've done this is using PowerShell, and setting it to "AutoAccept", but I've only done this on resource mailboxes and not user mailboxes.  If you set AutoAccept on a user's mailbox, by default it would accept everything, not sure if that is what they'd want to have happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell allows this, but as RMarkwald mentions, this may have unintended consequences.

Basically, someone with sufficient permissions can run this command on the desired mailboxes:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity username -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept
```

A better way may be to set you as a Delegate on the mailbox, allowing you to add events to their calendars. This is more of a manual process, but would probably have fewer unwelcome consequences.